# Error while injecting a Spring bean into a JSF ManagedBean

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a JSF ManagedBean which has a property that should be set by Spring. However, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert persistence.AuthDao@2f6e6ad9 of type class $Proxy166 to class persistence.AuthDao
at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:68)
at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.coerce(ELUtils.java:536)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder$Expression.evaluate(BeanBuilder.java:592)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder$BakedBeanProperty.set(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:606)
... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert persistence.AuthDao@2f6e6ad9 of type class $Proxy166 to class persistence.AuthDao
at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:397)
at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:66)
```

I have the ELresolver in faces-config.xml.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>authController</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>controllers.AuthController</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>authDao</property-name>
        <value>#{authDao}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>

<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

It seems that it can find the class, but the class is of another type ($Proxy166?, not sure where that comes from).

PS: Removing the ELResolver seems to do the trick; I thought explicitly providing managed-bean in faces-config.xml would override ELResolver. Is there any way of both of these to coexist, then? Similarly, if I provide both annotation and XML configuration for a bean, which one of these is preferred, or is there a way to merge them, provide some properties in annotation, some in XML?

PPS: After adding interfaces and changing my current classes to implement them, I get the following error:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'authDao' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type '$Proxy157 implementing
>   persistence.UserDao,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised'
>   to required type 'persistence.UserDaoImpl' for property 'userDao';
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert
>   value of type [$Proxy157 implementing
>   persistence.UserDao,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
>   to required type [persistence.UserDaoImpl] for property 'userDao': no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found. Please see server.log
>   for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a proxy of your class. You are implementing an interface, so spring creates a proxy around the interface, but you are trying to inject by concrete type. Switch to the interface instead (in the managed bean).

If you really need for some reason to inject by concrete class, you can use `@Scoped(proxyMode=ScopeProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`

Comment: Actually, I was not implementing an interface in this case, this was a quick demo. So, does Spring force me to use interfaces by default?

Comment: no. But your bean has an interface for sure, otherwise you won't get a $ProxyXX. If there was no interface, it would use cglib

Comment: Thanks for the help. There were no interfaces in my project though, just classes. Adding interfaces did not solve the problem either, I have added the error message above.

Comment: Show me the AuthDao class definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after adding the interfaces, the problem seems to go away. I had some UserDaoImpl references instead of UserDao, that was the cause of the latest error. I'm still not sure what the original problem was, but it seems creating interfaces for everything solved it somehow.